# jquery not working with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to make a message inbox which is being included on ajax call
on main page but on call of ajax for that inbox page it is loaded but jquery
click event is not working.........

```
<table> 
    <tr id="a"><td>aaaaaaaaaaaaa</td></tr>    
    <tr id="b"><td>showwwwwwwwwwwwwww</td></tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#a").on("click", function() {
    $("#b").slideToggle();
});
```

But the same inbox page working properly when loading it separately i mean 
without using ajax.
please help!

Comment: Have you searched for other questions in SO? You have to delegate event for dynamically loaded elements. `$(ancestor).on(event, element, function);`. It is good to use closest ancestor.

Comment: which elements are being updated/loaded by ajax?

Comment: @Sergio the complete inbox page is being included,the page contents are being ECHO by php.

Comment: Yes, but what elements? the `<table>` or just the content of thew table?

Comment: the complete page code is being echoed by php as ECHO "<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>"

Comment: Ok, then try Arun's answer...

Comment: Yes, but i couldnot understand what was problem in my code?

Comment: When you add new content dynamically the browser doesn't find the new elements in the DOM because they were not there when page loaded. So you need to reference a "old" element first, like `document` in Arun's example so you can delegate the event.

Comment: hmmm ok, so this document is the reference for my inbox page ?

Comment: it could be the parent of `<table>` it just has to be a element that is before the table in the DOM and not updated by ajax. Arun played safe and took `document`

Answer (score 1):

I assume the elements with id `a` and `b` are loaded dynamically to the page using an ajax request, in that case you need to use delegation based event handling as shown below

```
$(document).on("click", "#a", function() {
    $("#b").slideToggle();
});
```